# How to make infinity scroll on Scroll View in Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Scrollview in my app that shows a few slides, 
the default behaviour of the slides are when you reach the last one (ie slide 5 for example) is that it doesn't scroll more to the right, 
or when you go to the first one it doesn't scroll more to the left.

how do I make it infinity loop , meaning when I see the last slide, and I scroll more right, it will just scroll to the first one? 
(or from the first one left it will scroll to the last one)

here is my scrollViewDidScroll:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)

        let maximumHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.width
        let currentHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x

        // vertical
        let maximumVerticalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height
        let currentVerticalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y

        let percentageHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = currentHorizontalOffset / maximumHorizontalOffset
        let percentageVerticalOffset: CGFloat = currentVerticalOffset / maximumVerticalOffset


        /*
         * below code changes the background color of view on paging the scrollview
         */
        //        self.scrollView(scrollView, didScrollToPercentageOffset: percentageHorizontalOffset)


        /*
         * below code scales the imageview on paging the scrollview
         */
        let percentOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: percentageHorizontalOffset, y: percentageVerticalOffset)
        print ("present offset: ", percentOffset.x)
        if(percentOffset.x > 0 && percentOffset.x <= 0.25) {

            slides[0].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (0.25-percentOffset.x)/0.25, y: (0.25-percentOffset.x)/0.25)
            slides[1].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: percentOffset.x/0.25, y: percentOffset.x/0.25)

        } else if(percentOffset.x > 0.25 && percentOffset.x <= 0.50) {
            slides[1].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (0.50-percentOffset.x)/0.25, y: (0.50-percentOffset.x)/0.25)
            slides[2].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: percentOffset.x/0.50, y: percentOffset.x/0.50)

        } else if(percentOffset.x > 0.50 && percentOffset.x <= 0.75) {
            slides[2].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (0.75-percentOffset.x)/0.25, y: (0.75-percentOffset.x)/0.25)
            slides[3].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: percentOffset.x/0.75, y: percentOffset.x/0.75)

        } else if(percentOffset.x > 0.75 && percentOffset.x <= 1) {
            slides[3].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (1-percentOffset.x)/0.25, y: (1-percentOffset.x)/0.25)
            slides[4].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: percentOffset.x, y: percentOffset.x)

        } 
    }
```

Comment: check if you can use https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel. Instead of writing your own logic to achieve.

Comment: Here is the soultion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788657/ios-scrollview-infinite-paging-duplicate-end-caps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: ScrollView infinite paging - Duplicate end caps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788657/ios-scrollview-infinite-paging-duplicate-end-caps)

Comment: @ChiefMadog I need more information for that. What is slides ? is in an NSObject ? and you showing separate UIView for each slide or UIImageView ?

Comment: i'm showing a seperate UIView for each of them

Comment: @separate it's not becouse that post is just the basic funcionality of ending in the last slide, and i want it to continue scrolling left just return to the first one when finish

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your current implementation but your solution will be something like, I'm assuming your `slides` array contains UIView for each slide. Change the code according to your current implementation.

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if(if(scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0)) {
        CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width+scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset];
        [self rotateViewsRight];
    }
    else if(scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.bounds.size.width*2) {
        CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x-scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset];
        [self rotateViewsLeft];
    }
}

-(void)rotateViewsRight {
    UIView *endView = [slides lastObject];
    [slides removeLastObject];
    [slides insertObject:endView atIndex:0];
    [self setContentViewFrames];

}

-(void)rotateViewsLeft {
    UIView *endView = slides[0];
    [slides removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [slides addObject:endView];
    [self setContentViewFrames];

}

-(void) setContentViewFrames {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        UIView * view = slides[i];
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width*i, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is an obj C code, and i said i'm using swift, also in the comment for you,
in any way i wrote it in swift, and it doesn't work it has same funcionality of ending at the last slide